# How Legendary is a Legendary Treasure Site

Tags: age-of-wonders-3

When running around on the map I keep finding "Treasure Sites". For example a Ziggurat or a Forbidden Sanctum. I know that you can only use a single army stack to conquer the monsters that await you within. But since you can't see what armies are inside I have no idea what kind of difficulty encounter I'll end up running into.

They have an indication of difficulty, for example: "Legendary", "Mythical" and "Epic". 
What other difficulty Treasure Sites exist and what tier of armies can I expect in these Treasure Sites?

Comment: You can only use a single stack at the time, but you can attack multiple times offcourse. In a campaign, I often first throw a stack on a Mythical Ziggurat to weaken its inhabitants, losing the stack. Then I go in with the next stack... it's expensive, but the items go with me to the next round(s) and the units wouldn't have anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Wipqozn mentioned, when clicking 'enter' the combat dialog is shown, indicating the enemy force. You still have the option to cancel combat at that time.

The treasure site level (Legendary, Mythical, Epic etc.) indicate the maximum level of the items you can find after you've cleared the site. I do not have data yet if you always get an item of the same level as the treasure site.

**Edit**: after some testing, I've come up with the following results.

As mentioned before, the site level defines the maximum item level. The site level also defines the maximum enemy unit tier you may encounter. Depending on the number of enemies the maximum tier may be lower.

- **Strong**: 3 tier I units or 2 units with at least 1 unit of tier II
- **Epic**: 4 units, maximum tier II
- **Legendary**: 5 units, maximum tier IV
- **Mythical**: 6 units, maximum tier IV

I'll update with additional info once I've uncovered more sites.

Comment: Do you have an idea about the general difficulty of a treasure site level? (for example: Mythical sites seem to contain two tier 4 creatures) ANd about the difficulty ranking between the different levels? Is legendary harder then mythical or not?

Comment: @Arperum not yet, I'll look around (can't currently as I'm at work) and I'll keep an eye on it when playing.

Comment: If you get some dataz I can add thge bit I got into it, just ping me on [the Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge). I'm at work too right now, so I can't look at it either.

Answer (score 4):

You actually are able to see the armies inside a treasure site before attacking it. When you select "Enter" it will display the units you'll need to fight, and will give you the option to abort combat.

Comment: I found that out too tonight, I even started tracking what enemy tier there were in every site I tested, but then I got sidetracked by multiple wars...